# How to use nvidia geforce 920mx in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have try to run `software update` in my laptop (ASUS x4441U) and install additional drivers. Ubuntu detect that there is a proprietary driver for `nvidia`. I install the driver and restart.

However, when I click on `Setting | Details`, I got this information:

`Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)`

I expect the graphics driver to be nvidia, not builtin intel.

Also, I try to run this command:

```
gofrendi@asgard:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 07)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics 520
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 920MX] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM108M [GeForce 920MX]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_384_drm, nvidia_384
```

It seems the kernel driver in use is `nouveau`. I expect it to be `nvidia_384`.

How can I change that one? Or do I have some sort of miss-understanding here?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

1. Run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
2. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. Open http://www.nvidia.com/Download. Provide your VGA type, the website will show you the best driver version. Don't download the driver provided by the website. It is quite difficult to install the provided driver. You should turn off x session etc.
4. Install the driver from the ppa. My driver version is 390.42, so I type: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-390`

It works perfectly now
[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore for Ubuntu 20.04